convert Base64String to Uint8List in Flutter
in my MAUI App I am converting a jpeg into Base64String and sending this throughout Intent to my flutter App
here is MAUI Part


var path = FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory;
string fn = "invoice.jpeg";
var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fn);

byte[] data = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fullPath);

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);

string InvoiceImageText = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());



In Flutter I am recieving the string but I need to convert it to (bytesImg) so I can decode it and be able to use it
my current Flutter code looks like this


final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/mylogo.jpg');

final Uint8List bytesImg = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  
img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(bytesImg);



as you see above, my code currentely read ByteData from an Image saved in assets folder, but I need to replace that and use the Base64String Image recieved.
What types of conversion do I need to achive that? I am confused and appreciate your help
Thanks in advance!
Cheers

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64-constant.html

use base64Decode from dart:convert library

@Jason, U R a life saver! : D Big thnx, I will accept your suggestion as solution. Cheers!
